# Raku: Attempt to divide by zero when coercing Rational to Str

Tags: string, raku, zero, divide

I am crunching large amounts of data without a hitch until I added more data. The results are written to file as strings, but I received this error message and I am unable to find programming error after combing my codes for 2 days; my codes have been working fine before new data were added.

```
Died with the exception:
    Attempt to divide by zero when coercing Rational to Str
      in sub analyzeData at /home/xyz/numberCrunch.p6 line 2720
      in block  at /home/xyz/numberCrunch.p6 line 3363

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

The line 2720 is the line that outputs to file: $fh.say("$result");

So, Rational appears to be a delayed evaluation. Is there a way to force immediate conversion of Rational to decimals? Or make Rational smarter by enabling it to detect 0 denominators early?

Comment: .oO ( Perhaps... "The now wildly popular pragma `use ffs;`, that makes a range of Raku features fail fast, was first introduced in 202X. When first released it supported just `use ffs :Numerics` and all it did was throw an exception on construction of a `Rat` divided by zero, written in reaction to an earlier SO by @lisprogtor." )

Comment: Thank you very much raiph ! I will learn and try the ffs feature.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all: a `Rat` with a denominator of `0` is a perfectly legal Rational value.  So creating a `Rat` with a 0 denominator will not throw an exception on creation.

I see two issues really:

- how do you represent a `Rat` with a denominator of `0` as a string?
- how do you want your program to react to such a `Rat`?

When you represent a `Rat`s as a string, there is a good chance you will lose precision:

```
say 1/3;  # 0.333333
```

So the problem with `Rat` to string conversion is more general.  Fortunately, there's the `.raku` method that will *not* throw:

```
say (1/3).raku;   # <1/3>
say (42/0).raku;  # <42/0>
```

Now, if you want your program to just *not* print the value to the file handle if the denominator is 0, then you have several options:

- prefix with `try`

```
try $fh.say($result)
```

- check for 0 denominator explicitly

```
$fh.say($result) if $result.denominator
```

Finally, the final error message: "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" is a bit worrying.  If this is *not* a multi-threaded program, we should probably try to find out why that is happening: an execution error should *not* create a segfault.  If it is, then maybe we need to look at your code closer to find out if there are any race conditions on structures such as arrays and hashes.

Comment: It's a several thousand lines long code file. Who knows what lurks in there?

Comment: Which version of Rakudo?

Comment: Thank you very much Elizabeth Mattijsen and Holli. I am using the latest "Welcome to Rakudo(tm) v2021.04." I forgot to mention that I am crunching numbers on Dell i9 256G RAM workstation running 20 threads each reading from the same GIANT array to do its part of the task. I will utilize your suggestions to find the source of the errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

There is a perfectly logical reason that `1/0` doesn't immediately throw.

Let's say you have a floating point number that you want to coerce into a Rat, and back again.

```raku
my Num() $a = Inf;
my Rat() $b = $a;
my Num() $c = $b;

say $c;
```

What do you expect the `say $c` statement to print?

```
Inf
```

What would happen if you wrote `say $b`?

```raku
say $b;
```

```
Attempt to divide by zero when coercing Rational to Str
```

What are the contents of `$b`?

```raku
say $b.nude.join('/');
```

```
1/0
```

---

Now what if you do a division and immediately coerce it to a Num?

```raku
say ( 1/0).Num;
say ( 0/0).Num;
say (-1/0).Num;
```

```
Inf
NaN
-Inf
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why is `Inf` represented in a Rat as `1/0`? That’s wrong mathematically, and at the same time there are perfectly reasonable alternatives available: `Inf/1`.

Comment: @DanBron Per Wikipedia, "[number divided by zero] may generate positive or negative infinity by the IEEE 754 floating point standard, ... an exception, ... an error message, cause the program to terminate, result in **a special not-a-number value**, or a crash." For its floating point `Num` type/representation, Raku represents the "special not-a-number" positive and negative infinity values as `Inf` and `-Inf`. For its `Rat` type/representation it chooses `1/0` / `-1/0`. (`Rat` is defined as `Rational[Int, uint64]`, i.e. integer over integer, so `Num`'s `Inf` values can't be used.)

Comment: @raiph Ah, yes, I’d forgotten IEEE permits this (and my own fave lang, J, defines 1/0 as inf as well). That Rat is an abstraction over int and not num explains why it couldn’t take a mathematically purer approach. Thanks for the insights.

Comment: Thank you very much Brad Gilbert, Dan Bron, and raiph !